# The bootstrap table with detached header

Tags: html, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to create a simple bootstrap table from HTML and JSON input data. For some reason, however, the table header seems to form a separate table (?) with an additional first column. Why is it so?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <table data-toggle="table" id="fragmenterTable" data-search="true" data-show-refresh="true"
            data-show-toggle="true" data-show-fullscreen="true" data-show-columns="true"
            data-show-columns-toggle-all="true" data-detail-view="true" data-show-export="true"
            data-click-to-select="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-pagination="true"
            data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]" data-side-pagination="client">

            <thead>
                <th data-field="Molecule">
                    Molecule
                </th>
                <th data-field="Smiles">
                    Smiles
                </th>
                <th data-field="MolWeight">
                    MolWeight
                </th>
                <th data-field="HBA">
                    HBA
                </th>
                <th data-field="HBD">
                    HBD
                </th>
                <th data-field="TPSA">
                    TPSA
                </th>
                <th data-field="HeavyAtoms">
                    HeavyAtoms
                </th>
                <th data-field="Charge">
                    Charge
                </th>
                <th data-field="RingCount">
                    RingCount
                </th>
                <th data-field="AromaticRings">
                    AromaticRings
                </th>
                <th data-field="AliphaticRings">
                    AliphaticRings
                </th>
                <th data-field="RotatableBonds">
                    RotatableBonds
                </th>
                <th data-field="cLogP">
                    cLogP
                </th>
                <th data-field="MorganFingerprints">
                    MorganFingerprints
                </th>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

<!-- Include jQuery and other required 
  files for Bootstrap -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.1/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var in_json = 'fragments_test.json'

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fragmenterTable').append('<tbody>');
        // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
        $.getJSON(in_json,
            function (data) {
                $.each(data.data, function (key, value) {
                    var row = '';

                    row += '<tr>';
                    for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            row += '<td>' + 'mol2 content' + '</td>';
                        } else {
                            row += '<td>' + value[i] + '</td>';
                        }
                    }
                    row += '</tr>';

                    $('#fragmenterTable').append(row);

                });

            });
        $('#fragmenterTable').append('</tbody>');
    });

</script>
```

My json file looks as follows (fragments_test.json):

```
{"columns":["Molecule","Smiles","MolWeight","HBA","HBD","TPSA","HeavyAtoms","Charge","RingCount","AromaticRings","AliphaticRings","RotatableBonds","cLogP","MorganFingerprints"],"data":[["CHEMBL155926\n     RDKit          2D\n\n  5  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000\n   12.7500  -12.1378    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   13.4649  -12.5497    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   14.1756  -12.1378    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   14.8903  -12.5497    0.0000 Cl  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   12.0352  -12.5497    0.0000 Cl  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n  1  2  2  0\n  1  5  1  0\n  2  3  1  0\n  3  4  1  0\nM  END\n","Cl\/C=C\/CCl",110.97,0,0,0.0,5,0,0,0,0,1,1.98,{}],["\n     RDKit          2D\n\n  8  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000\n    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 R   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    7.3288  -19.6010    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    8.0436  -19.1861    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    8.7585  -19.6010    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    8.0436  -18.3656    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 R   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    9.4733  -19.1861    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    7.3288  -17.9508    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n  1  2  1  0\n  3  2  1  0\n  4  3  1  0\n  3  5  2  0\n  6  4  1  0\n  4  7  2  0\n  5  8  1  0\nM  ISO  2   1   8   6   1\nM  END\n","[1*]C(=O)\/C(C[8*])=N\/O",85.06,3,1,49.66,6,0,0,0,0,2,0.04,{}],["\n     RDKit          2D\n\n  9  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000\n    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 R   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   16.4212   -8.5322    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   15.7020   -8.1276    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   16.4304   -9.3574    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   14.9893   -8.5402    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   15.2835   -7.4104    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   16.1087   -7.4104    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   14.2766   -8.1318    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   13.5639   -8.5444    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n  1  2  1  0\n  2  3  1  0\n  2  4  2  0\n  5  3  1  0\n  3  6  1  0\n  3  7  1  0\n  8  5  1  0\n  9  8  1  0\nM  ISO  1   1   1\nM  END\n","[1*]C(=O)C(C)(C)CCC",113.18,1,0,17.07,8,0,0,0,0,3,2.01,{}],["\n     RDKit          2D\n\n  6  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000\n    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 R   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    9.1138  -22.8236    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    8.3488  -23.2242    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    9.8460  -23.2884    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    8.3117  -24.0895    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    7.6166  -22.7594    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n  1  2  1  0\n  2  3  1  0\n  2  4  2  0\n  3  5  1  0\n  3  6  1  0\nM  ISO  1   1   1\nM  END\n","[1*]C(=O)C(C)C",71.1,1,0,17.07,5,0,0,0,0,1,0.84,{}],["\n     RDKit          2D\n\n  8  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000\n    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 R   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.0188   -0.1607    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.4313    0.5510    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.8062   -0.1607    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.0188    1.2669    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -1.2563    0.5510    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.4313    1.9828    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.8062    1.2669    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n  1  2  1  0\n  2  3  1  0\n  2  4  2  0\n  3  5  1  0\n  3  6  1  0\n  5  7  1  0\n  5  8  1  0\nM  ISO  1   1   1\nM  END\n","[1*]C(=O)C(C)C(C)O",101.12,2,1,37.3,7,0,0,0,0,2,0.2,{}],["\n     RDKit          2D\n\n  7  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000\n    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 R   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   24.9472  -17.9755    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   25.6590  -17.5645    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   24.9472  -18.8018    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   26.3752  -17.9755    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   25.6590  -16.7425    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   26.3759  -18.8369    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n  1  2  1  0\n  2  3  1  0\n  2  4  2  0\n  3  5  1  0\n  3  6  1  0\n  5  7  1  0\nM  ISO  1   1   1\nM  END\n","[1*]C(=O)C(C)CC",85.13,1,0,17.07,6,0,0,0,0,2,1.23,{}]]}
```

Also, the pagination does not work, I assume it's because of the "detached" header.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should format your json data structure to be like this:

`https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/json/data1.json`

where for each object will have its own fields:

```
[
    {
        "Molecule": "CHEMBL155926\n     RDKit          2D\n\n  5  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000\n   12.7500  -12.1378    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   13.4649  -12.5497    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   14.1756  -12.1378    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   14.8903  -12.5497    0.0000 Cl  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   12.0352  -12.5497    0.0000 Cl  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n  1  2  2  0\n  1  5  1  0\n  2  3  1  0\n  3  4  1  0\nM  END\n",
        "Smiles": "Cl/C=C/CCl",
        "MolWeight": 110.97,
        "HBA": 0,
        "HBD": 0,
        "TPSA": 0.0,
        "HeavyAtoms": 5,
        "Charge": 0,
        "RingCount": 0,
        "AromaticRings:": 0,
        "AliphaticRings": 0,
        "RotatableBonds": 1,
        "cLogP": 1.98,
        "MorganFingerprints": {}
    }
]
```

After that, you can use the `data-url` instead of the function that "organizing" the `json` file as:

```html
        <table data-toggle="table" id="fragmenterTable" data-search="true" data-show-refresh="true"
            data-show-toggle="true" data-show-fullscreen="true" data-show-columns="true"
            data-show-columns-toggle-all="true" data-detail-view="true" data-show-export="true"
            data-click-to-select="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-pagination="true"
            data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]" data-side-pagination="client"
            data-url="fragments_test.json">
```

Once you will provide `bootstrap-table` the correct formatted `json` file, it will work perfect.

Comment: The thing is that I want to modify one of the column content (create a div inside the cell). Can I do it after reading the whole table  before?

Comment: Sure, you can use the `data-formatter` see docs example: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/column-options/formatter.html